# Junit Test not working with Gradle Project in InteliJ IDEA 2016.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

My Gradle Project Cannot Run JUnit Test in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 version.
When I Use @Test Annotation and Run it, it executes as a Gradle Task, notas Junit Test. When I Click right hotkey on test method, not exist 'Create Junit ..'
option (this option is available in last version.)

- I installed idea Junit Plugin.
- It's working on IDEA 2016.2 version.

has anyone see the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried reimporting your gradle project?

Comment: I retried improt many times. but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

it's my project config error,
just modify Settings -> Build, Execution, Development -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Disable Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle resolve this problem.